# Take a specific action on every action using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am having real problems debugging an intermittent issue with our Selenium Tests. It would be a genuine issue in the site I am testing or it could be a condition our tests are not handling.

I would like to take a specific action every time the webdriver does something e.g. take a screenshot or log the action. In this way I can look back at a failed test and see the successful steps and the point the test failed.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `WebDriver` event listener.

http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/event-listener/